# Can't XClass eventnews Location and Organizer

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, tx-news

I like to extend (own extension) eventnews (https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews) to use tt_address (https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/tt_address) records for locations and organizers. The TCA is no problem, but XClass'ing does not work:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['GeorgRinger\\Eventnews\\Domain\\Model\\Location'] = array(
    'className' => 'TYPO3\\TtAddress\\Domain\\Model\\Address',
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['GeorgRinger\\Eventnews\\Domain\\Model\\Organizer'] = array(
    'className' => 'TYPO3\\TtAddress\\Domain\\Model\\Address',
);
```

Has it something to do with the PHPDoc annotations in Classes/Domain/Model/News.php ?

XClass'ing the News Model will help maybe, but i want to understand why it's not possible to use the code above

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the proxy class generator in the news extension. It changes the way classes are loaded in order to allow overriding and extending the news model.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ProxyClassGenerator/Index.html